# Continuity of a function defined on $\{1/n:n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

This is problem 10 of chapter 3 of *A Course in Calculus and Real Analysis First Edition* by *Sudhir R. Ghorpade and Balmohan V. Limaye*.

> Let $D:=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$ and $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be any function. Show that $f$ is continuous at $1/n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , and $f$ is continuous at $0$ if and only if $f(1/n)\to f(0)$.

A reader of this post may assume the first assertion, i.e., $f$ is continuous at $1/n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**My difficulty is in proving the second assertion.**

If $f$ is continuous at $0$, then since $1/n \to 0$, it is clear from the sequential criterion that $f(1/n) \to f(0)$.

Conversely, assume $f(1/n)\to f(0)$. Let $(y_n)$ be any sequence in $D$ such that $y_n\to0$. If there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y_n=0$ for all $n\geq n_0$, then $f(y_n)=f(0)$ for all $n\geq n_0$ and the statement is true.

Also note that if $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $x_n :=1/n$, then $f(x_{n_k})\to f(0)$. To see this, since $f(1/n)\to f(0)$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(1/n)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_1$. Since $x_{n_k}=1/n_k$ and $n_k\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$, it follows that there is $k_o \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_k>n_1$ for all $k\geq k_0$. All this implies, $|f(x_{n_k})-f(0)|=|f(1/n_k)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ for $k\geq k_o$.

Now all I have to prove is that any sequence in $D$ which is eventually non-zero and converges to $0$ is eventually a subsequence of $(1/n)$. This will also allow me prove the remaining case where, past a certain term, all terms of the sequence are both $0$ and non-zero.

So, my question is: **How do I prove that for any sequence in $D$ which is eventually non-zero and converges to $0$, a tail of this sequence is a subsequence of $(1/n)$? Is this even true?**

Since I am only a student, I would like to know if I've made any mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not true. For instance, the sequence $1,1,\frac12,\frac12,\frac13,\frac13,\frac14,\frac14,\ldots$ is *not* a subsequence of $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. More generally, none of if tails is a subsequence of $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac1n\right)=f(0)$. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\left\lvert f(0)-f\left(\frac1n\right)\right\rvert<\varepsilon.\tag1$$Now, let $\delta=\frac1N$. So, it follows from $(1)$ that$$\left(\forall x\in\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}\cup\{0\}\right):\lvert x\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(0)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon,$$since$$\lvert x\rvert<\delta\implies x=0\text{ or }x=\frac1n\text{ for some }n>N.$$So, $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Would you answer change if I changed my question as follows :  How do I prove that for any sequence in $D$ which is eventually non-zero and converges to $0$, a tail of this sequence is a subsequence of $(1/n)$? I am almost sure this is true but can't rigourously prove it.

Comment: It is **not** true. Take the sequence$$1,1,\frac12,\frac12,\frac13,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots$$for instance.

Comment: @DS2830 I've done it.